# Compute monthly moving averages with a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib, apply, seaborn

I have data like this.

```
 Date_of_event               - expenditure
 2016-04-04 09:20:04.903     - 50000
 2015-04-04 09:20:04.903     - 40000
 2016-08-04 09:20:04.903     - 70000
 2017-01-04 09:20:04.903     - 35000
 2011-04-04 09:20:04.903     - 250000
 2013-04-06 09:20:04.903     - 500
 2016-07-09 09:20:04.903     - 1090000
```

I want to plot the six month moving average of average monthly expenditure using seaborn or matplotlib. As a first step, I was trying to compute average monthly expenditure, using resample, so I then then group by month. However I get the following error when I use this code:

```
df['Date_of_event'] = df['Date_time'].resample('M')

Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'.
```

". Note the .dt.days and .dt.month methods work find on my df['Date_of_event'], so it seems to be a datetime object.

Is there a way to resample these datetimes to be year+ month, or an easier way to compute moving averages?

Comment: do you want the moving window to be within the month such that you end up with multiple values per month? or would you like to have monthly totals, which are *then* averaged within a moving window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resample method only works if the datetime values are in the dataframe's index.  It seems that this isn't the case yet.  You can do this by using the below code and compute the monthly totals like this:

```
df = df.set_index('Date_time').resample('M').sum()
```

The documentation for this is in the link below.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Comment: As of version 0.19 you can use columns for resampling too (you need to use the `on` parameter).

Comment: Yes.We can use df= df.resample('M',on=''Date_of_event'').sum() from version 0.19.